# About parentheses, boolean logic, and '\n'

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

I found out that (true && false) gives 0, yet true && false(without parentheses) gives 1.
This question might be dumb cause I just started learning C++, but I just couldn't find the answer anywhere.

I ran the following:

```
cout << (true && false) << '\n';
cout << true && false << '\n';
cout << (true && false == true);
```

It gave me:

```
    0
    10
```

After seeing this, I got even more confused:

1. What's the difference between `(true && false)` and `true && false` (without parentheses)?
2. Because `true && false` gives me `1`, so I thought that `true && false` without parentheses is `true`. However, `(true && false == true)` gives me `0`. Why? Is it because that `0` and `1` do not necessarily indicate `false` and `true`?
3. Also, it seems like the `'\n'` in the second row doesn't work. Why?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Parentheses only change semantics in the context of the surrounding operators. You are ignoring those (I'm talking about `operator<<` and `operator==`, although the latter in your case does not change anything).

Comment: With operator precedence the 2nd line is: `(cout << true) && (false << '\n');`

Comment: Actually I have seen people talking about the difference between `a && b || c` and `a || b && c`, but not until now did I realize that << and == are ignored by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown on on a [table of operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `<<` has precedence 7, `&&` has precedence 14

As a result, the expression `cout << true && false << '\n';` can be re-written as:

```
(cout << true) && (false << '\n');
```

This evaluates as:

```
(cout << true)         // Output: "1"; Evaluates to an ostream-object.
(false << '\n')        // No output; Evaluates to 0, the '\n' "disappears"
[ostream-object] && 0; // No output; Evaluates to 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`cout << true && false << '\n';`
is the same as
`(cout << true) && (false << '\n');`

`true` (1) is streamed to `cout`, returning a reference to the stream.
`&&`
`false` (0) is left bitshifted `\n` (10) bits, resulting in 0.

The stream is now in boolean context (because of the `&&`) and will be `true` via its conversion operator `operator bool ()` since it's still in a good state.

We're left with `true && 0` which results in `false`.

```
(cout << true)   &&   (false << '\n')   ==
(cout << true)   &&   (false << 10)     ==   // right side: 0 << 10
(cout << true)   &&   0                 =>   // true is sent out here
    bool(cout)   &&   0                 =>
         true    &&   0
               false
```

Answer (score 2):

`&&` has lower precedence than `<<` and `==`, so the code behaves as:

```
cout << (true && false) << '\n';
(cout << true) && (false << '\n');
cout << (true && (false == true));
```

In the first line, you are anding true and false.
In the second line, you are streaming true, and shifting false left by the ascii value of newline (which has no effect).
In the third line, you are testing if false is equal to true, which yields false.

Comment: @drescherjm It's still completely accurate, though. Personally, this makes more sense to me than abelenky's answer does.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't see any way for `cout << (true && false == true)` to print `1`. OP has had that part parenthesized since the beginning.

Comment: You're right, I was focused on `cout << true && false << '\n';`. My bad!